# Choosing 5 out of 40 beads

Tags: probability

Have $40$ beads, $5$ of which are **winning** beads. A user has a chance to win, they need to select $5$ winning beads in $5$ tries. Is the probability of this happening:

$$\frac{5}{40} \cdot \frac{ 4}{39} \cdot \frac{ 3}{38} \cdot \frac{2}{37} \cdot \frac{ 1}{36} $$
Or am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming no replacement and each remaining bead is equally likely to be chosen at each step, it is as you say.  It can be simplified if desired as $\dfrac{1}{\binom{40}{5}}$ and described using the [hypergeometric distribution instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%20and%20statistics,that%20contains%20exactly%20objects%20with) if you so choose.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Assuming that the beads are different, the number of ways of choosing these winning beads one after the other is $5.4.3.2.1$ and the number of ways of choosing any five beads is $40.39.38.37.36$.
Consequently, the probability becomes what you wrote down.